# RN Flatlist pagingenabled and scrolllength

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create the following design using a FlatList

[image: One can see the start of the next item and end of the previous item]

My first take was this:

```
    const SCREENWIDTH = 375
    const COMPONENTWIDTH = 325
    const OFFSET = (SCREENWIDTH - COMPONENTWIDTH) / 2


    <FlatList
    style={{flex: 1}}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
      length: COMPONENTWIDTH,
      offset: OFFSET + COMPONENTWIDTH * index,
      index,
    })}
    pagingEnabled
    horizontal
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingLeft: OFFSET, paddingRight: OFFSET }}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View
            style={{
              width: COMPONENTWIDTH,
              height: 300,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: colors.white,
                borderRadius: 20,
                flex: 1,
                marginLeft: 10,
                marginRight: 10,
              }}
            >
            </View>
          </View>)}
    />
```

However paging seems to scroll SCREENWIDTH, not COMPONENTWIDTH

Any recomendations?